# Eclipse won't delete mp3

Tags: android, eclipse, mp3

I have an MP3 in raw folder and when I try delete it, it just comes back. I don't have any use for it and want it gone. 
Not sure what to do?
Any help?

Comment: remove it using the FileExplorer of your OperatingSystem

Comment: Tried that but it says need permission?

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: Sudo or run as administrator to remove the file if you get an error message

Comment: Windows vista :/ hehe, I've tried changing ownership of file but does not let me

Comment: Tried running as administrator still comes back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should terminat the Eclipse process and virtual machine (dwm) on task manager and then go to project folder and delete it from that location.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the folder where is your project(i.e. with My Comupter) and remove it from there. Or you maybe need just refresh your project when you click on left panel(package explorer). Right click on you project folder and refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD as Administrator:

1. Start
2. Type cmd
3. Right click > open as Administrator

Then use `cd` to go the folder containing the file and use `del` to delete it:

```
C:\> cd path\to\dir\
C:\path\to\dir\> del file.mp3
```